# How Get ID value from router in view using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I have a router.js and a view.js

I want the value of ID passed from router.js page in my view page. How can i get that??

**Here is my router:**

```
/**
 * Created by HP on 6/26/2014.
 */

var app = app || {};
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'color/:id': 'color'
    },
    index: function(){
        console.log("index called");
    },
    color: function(id){
        console.log("color called"+id);
        //viewPage.render(id);
    }
});

new app.Router;
Backbone.history.start();
```

In my view i want the value of id which i need to set in a html element
**Here is my View**
/**
 * Created by HP on 6/17/2014.
 */

```
// site/js/views/library.js
var app = app || {};
app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
 el: '#ulMenu',
 initialize: function(options) {
this.collection = new app.Library();
this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
this.render();
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
 },
    events:{
        'click':'show'

    },
    show: function(){

        this.subRender();
    },
 render: function() {
      },

    subRender: function() {
        $("#content").html("Color Name: ");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Did I miss something or you just need to create a `setColor` method on the view then in the router call `viewPage.setColor(id);viewPage.render();` ?

Comment: Could you post your View code as well, please? You're on the right track, but it's easier to give code samples if we can see your views too.

Comment: @BGR if this is the set method then what will be the get mechanism in view?

Comment: @AlexP thanks for your response.Here is my view code : var app = app || {}; app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({ el: '#ulMenu', initialize: function(options) { this.collection = new app.Library(); this.collection.fetch({reset: true}); this.render(); this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render ); }, events:{ 'click':'show' }, show: function(){ this.subRender(); }, render: function() { }, subRender: function() { $("#content").html("Color Name: ");// I need the id here. } });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can try passing all your arguments as options

**Router**

```
var app = app || {};
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'color/:id': 'color'
    },
    index: function(){
        console.log("index called");
    },
    color: function(id){
        console.log("color called"+id);
        var libraryView = new LibraryView({
              id : id    //passing it as option to views initalize.
         });
    }
});

new app.Router;
Backbone.history.start();
```

**View**

```
var app = app || {};
app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
 el: '#ulMenu',
 initialize: function(options) {
this.receivedId = this.options.id; // id is catched here
this.collection = new app.Library();
this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
this.render();
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
 },
    events:{
        'click':'show'

    },
    show: function(){

        this.subRender();
    },
 render: function() {
      },

    subRender: function() {
        $("#content").html("Color Name: ");
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code.

```
color: function(id){
console.log("color called"+id);
viewPage = new ViewPage({model: new Model({'id':id})})
viewPage.render(id);
}
```

Comment: thanks.i think this is the way of passing value.Then what will be the next step i.e How can i get the value in my view page?

Comment: Please use following line to get the 'id' in your view .  [Please click 'Up'icon if you liked my previous answer]      this.model.get('id')